# PHP/MySQL: fetch range instead of array?

Tags: php, mysql, range

I have a table which contains ~1600 promo codes.
I have another table that contains ONLY used codes.

I would like to display a HTML table that shows ONLY unused codes.
As I want to avoid showing hundreds of lines, I'm wandering if it is possible to show ranges of unused codes.

Example of what I dont want:

```
"1A1" => unused
"1A2" => unused
"1A3" => unused
[...]
```

Example of what I want:

```
"1A1" to "3F2" => 52 unused codes
"4A1" to "12E3" => 359 unused codes
"13A2" to "Blah blah blah" => 451 unused codes
[...]
```

I'm using PHP and MySQL.
As of now there are more unused codes than used ones, but in a few days it will be the contrary.

Thanks a lot for your help!

**Edit: Perhaps I could do a different approach. Could you help me with that? I want to store all the codes in an array, all the used codes in another array, create an array of unused codes by comparing both arrays, and define ranges based on that third array. That would allow me to make only 2 queries**

Comment: A simple approach would be to start counting from the first time you encounter an unused code (storing that key) and reset the counter when you reach a used code, while storing the previous as the last used for that range.

Comment: Would that mean making a query for each code?

Comment: Perhaps I could do a different approach. Could you help me with that?
I want to store all the codes in an array, all the used codes in another array, create an array of unused codes by comparing both arrays, and define ranges based on that third array. That would allow me to make only 2 queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it by storing the SQL results as an object inside JS and doing all the dirty work in JS to avoid sending tons of db queries.